# Why is ProjectM not opening in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: fonts, 17.04, music

I installed ProjectM via the Ubuntu Software portal, and after launching, the icon sits on the doc, highlights a few times, and then closes.

Trying it in the terminal generates this:

```
dir:/usr/share/projectM/config.inp 
reading ~/.projectM/config.inp 
[projectM] config file: /home/jason/.projectM/config.inp
No Textures Loaded from "/usr"/share/projectM/textures
Could not open font file: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
```

Is that "/usr" section indicating a typo in the config file maybe?

Did the font not get autoinstalled with the projectM package? Maybe an apt-update / apt-upgrade can fix it. I'll work on it myself but also thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the font-related error message, I changed the config.inp file from this:

```
Title Font = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
Menu Font = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

to this:

```
Title Font = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
Menu Font = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

ProjectM opens correctly for me now!

Answer (score 6):

Just install `ttf-dejavu`:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
I managed to 'fix' the font error by going to the /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ folder and renaming the 'dejavu' folder as 'ttf-dejavu'. Now ProjectM opens but the textures are still not opening.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/746609)

Comment: @OwenHines: Looks like a partial answer to me.

Comment: It would be better to create a symbolic link as an alias of `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu` instead of renaming it: `sudo ln -sT dejavu /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu`

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yeah, I just went with the preset review response that I thought was the closest. Probably better to do a "this should be a comment" response. Sorry about that.

Comment: @OwenHines: Partial answers are acceptable. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/271411.

Comment: I actually reversed the advice of the answer, and changed the config file to  point to the dejavu folder. ProjectM is working now!

Comment: just fixing the font folder did the trick. everything is working